# How does the Composer trick with re-defining the packagist repo work?

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, packagist

In the issue (#3156) discussion "[composer is very slow](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3156)" on the [Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer) GitHub page is [suggested](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3156#issuecomment-110389570) to

> re-define the packagist repo with a https:// url in the global config using:

```
$ composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

> That should work around the downgrade issue, but it'd be interesting to resolve it of course.

<strike>It really brings a appreciable speed boost.</strike> I've just tested this for Zend Framework 2 (see test below).

<strike>**How does it work?** (Why does disabling of the `allow_ssl_downgrade` option make the process faster?)</strike>

---

**EDIT**

I run `composer create-project zendframework/zendframework` combining two factors: cache and the re-defining the packagist repo with turning `allow_ssl_downgrade` off. I got following results for the resulting four cases:

Default configs:

```
config: default ([repositories.packagist.url] https?://packagist.org, [repositories.packagist.allow_ssl_downgrade] true)
cache: empty (composer clear-cache)
result: 3m38s

config: default ([repositories.packagist.url] https?://packagist.org, [repositories.packagist.allow_ssl_downgrade] true) 
cache:  not empty
result: 54s

config: changed ([repositories.packagist.url] https://packagist.org)
cache:  empty (composer clear-cache)
result: 3m34s

config: changed ([repositories.packagist.url] https://packagist.org)
cache:  not empty
result: 56s
```

Summary: The "trick" with disabling `allow_ssl_downgrade` brings no speed boost.

Nevertheless it would be nice to know: **What does the `allow_ssl_downgrade` option actually do?** (What does this "downgrading" mean? What are the advantages and disadvantages?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the second time you run `composer create-project zendframework/zendframework` it took everything from composer's cache instead of downloading it again!

You can see that it outputs something like the following where it say `Loading from cache` if you run it a second time:

```
Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.5.2)
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.5.2)
    Loading from cache
```

Make sure to run `composer clear-cache` between your tests to get reliable results.

#### EDIT//

If we have a look into Composer's source code we can find [this line](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/41392ace56650d06823a74091bb21df790aaefc1/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php#L388-390):

```
if ($this->allowSslDowngrade) {
    $this->url = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $this->url);
}
```

If `allowSslDowngrade = true`
The main file is retrieved over https ([see here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/41392ace56650d06823a74091bb21df790aaefc1/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php#L373)) the rest over http because that's a way faster. The integrity of the other files are checked via the sha256, which should be sufficient protection against MITM attacks.

If `allowSslDowngrade = false`
Everything is retrieved over https

The differences in your measurements might be the result of varying Internet speed or server cpu/network load or something.

Comment: @automatix I edited my answer hope this makes it clear for you

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually clear your cache in between? Because that would also significantly decrease the install time on a second run.

I was not able to create such a big difference by changing the configuration and clearing the cache in between.

Comment: Yes, it's a good point. I performed the test again and updated the question.